# How to make async ApiView DRF

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have got a code which count something from API, it works slowly, i need to upgrade it, how can i make the calling two functions like async?

```py
class CountView(APIView):
    permissions = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request):
        
       user_token= UpdatedUser.objects.get(user=request.user).access_token
       provider = CounterAPI(user_token, request.user)


       count_weeks = provider.count_something('w')
       count_months = provider.count_something('m')


        result = {
            'weeks': count_weeks ,
            'months': count_months 
        }
        return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I need to make async count_weeks and count_months